# How do I exclude a tensor from the torch.no_grad?

Tags: python, pytorch

If I am using the torch.no_grad decorator like this:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad = True)
@torch.no_grad() # Or like this: with torch.no_grad()
def func(x):
  a = torch.tensor([1.])
  b = a * 2
  b.backward()
  print(a.grad)
  ........
  return x ** 2
z = func(x)
print(z.requires_grad)
```

What if I want to have no_grad (to save time/memory computation) for everything except for a selective few amount of tensors? How do I do what I did above?